# How change my TEXMFHOME directory config

Tags: texlive, texmf, tlmgr, texlive-2018, texmf.cnf

I use Texlive 2018 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I wanted to change my TEXMFHOME directory to hide it. I did it just creating a usertree in "~/.texmf"

I've tried `if [ -d ~/.texmf ] ; then     export TEXMFHOME=~/.texmf; fi` to change TEXMFHOME value and then I tried to install a package to check if it was working:

```
 sudo tlmgr install doublestroke
```

And i got the following error:

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /home/username/texmf!
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/username/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 6424.
```

I'd tried a lot of solutions presented here, including checking the values in my 'texmf.cnf' file, but none of them worked. The point is I don't know why my tlmgr insists to seach my .tlpdb file in the wrong directory.

**I simply want a tlmgr with all my directories in $HOME hidden.** By the way, I said this when i ran "install-tl" to install it because I changed my TEXMFHOME directory during the installation(but seems it ignored).

Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have run install-tl (which sounds like the vanilla TeX Live install script), but are running a Debian packaged TeX Live tlmgr? What kind of installation are we talking about?

Comment: I just downloaded, unpacked the install-tl-unx.tar.gz (http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) and ran it '$ sudo perl install-tl'. It wasnt a .deb file or none of this kinda, just a perl script. As I said, while I was setting it up I chose my TEXMFHOME to be a hidden one.

Comment: What is the output of  `echo $TEXMFHOME`? Add your texlive variables to your question, it can help.

Comment: @sztruks the output is `/home/username/.texmf` after the command `export TEXMFHOME=~/.texmf`

Comment: @TeXnician `which tlmgr` returned `/usr/bin/tlmgr`. I guess thats nothing wrong with this output.

Comment: Okay, is `/usr/bin/tlmgr` a symlink to your TeX installation by install-tl? Again, I would suspect that you have some `texlive-…` package installed from the repos because of the error message you got. (Sometimes this happens to resolve dependencies of TeX editors etc.)

Comment: @TeXnician Indeed! after do`file /usr/bin/tlmgr` turnout it is a symlink. The exact output was `/usr/bin/tlmgr: symbolic link to ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl`

Comment: That does actually support my suspicion. The usual location of an `install-tl` run is `/usr/local/share` whereas `/usr/share` is used by distro packages. Try removing them and recreating all the symlinks to the TeX Live installation (`/path/to/real/tlmgr path add` should do the trick).

Comment: @TeXnician I didnt get it. Should I unistall all packages installed using `install-tl` and try to run it again inside `/usr/local/share`? I also want to know which application do I use to create the symlinks and which symlinks I should create.

Comment: You should uninstall all texlive distro packages. `install-tl` installs to a location you specify and using that location and `/path/to/tlmgr path add` you can create the symlinks.